# Create a home virtual network

Tags: networking, virtualization, arch-linux

I can't seem to get answers to this question. I want to setup up 2-3 computers in my house to run Linux based virtual machines fed from my dedicated Arch Linux server. I need them to have full sound and video support. At my workplace we use VMware (View), but that is too cost prohibited for me to deploy for my wife and the two 10 year olds. I have tried Virtualbox machines and they are fine, but I cannot get sound working.  Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I should have made it clearer... These virtual machines will run on top of a very limited xserver (very low resouces). To answer my own question I stumbled upon someones blog that suggested rdesktop (I was using xfreerdp... Sound wouldn't work). Well the short answer is now it works. Here is the command for anyone googling this subject.

[code]rdesktop -r sound=local server:port[/code]